# SQL Server query to divide the amount by the number of days that person worked on a project removing non business day from another table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to get divide the amount by the number of days that person worked on a project

For example,
If the person worked on "a" project for an amount of 30, between 25 June to 30 June. I want to distribute the money equally into each day he worked removing the weekend and other holidays (that are present in table T3). Working days answer should be 4 and  price is calculated by Price /Workin day i.e. 30/4 or 7.5 he earned each day. And create a table T4 as result below.

For example,
A table with the start date of the task, the end date of the task, and Price- say  T1

| Project | Start Date | End Date | Amount | Person |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | 25/6/2021 | 30/6/2021 | 30 | John |
| b | 2/7/2021 | 5/7/2021 | 20 | John |
| c | 29/6/2021 | 5/7/2021 | 60 | Mac |

And a second table with Person and WorkId say T2

| Person | Work Id |
| --- | --- |
| John | J_123 |
| Mac | M_324 |

and Third table with a calendar that showed business days T3

| Date | Buisness days | Word Id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 25/6/2021 | Y | J_123 |
| 26/6/2021 | N | J_123 |
| 27/6/2021 | N | J_123 |
| 28/6/2021 | Y | J_123 |
| 29/6/2021 | Y | J_123 |
| 30/6/2021 | Y | J_123 |
| 1/7/2021 | N | J_123 |
| 2/7/2021 | Y | J_123 |
| 3/7/2021 | N | J_123 |
| 4//2021 | N | J_123 |
| 5//2021 | Y | J_123 |
| 25/6/2021 | Y | M_324 |
| 26/6/2021 | N | M_324 |
| 27/6/2021 | N | M_324 |
| 28/6/2021 | Y | M_324 |
| 29/6/2021 | Y | M_324 |
| 30/6/2021 | Y | M_324 |
| 1/7/2021 | N | M_324 |
| 2/7/2021 | Y | M_324 |
| 3/7/2021 | N | M_324 |
| 4//2021 | N | M_324 |
| 5//2021 | Y | M_324 |

Result -T4

| Date | Project | Word Id | Price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 25/6/2021 | a | J_123 | 7.5 |
| 28/6/2021 | a | J_123 | 7.5 |
| 29/6/2021 | a | J_123 | 7.5 |
| 30/6/2021 | a | J_123 | 7.5 |
| 2/7/2021 | b | J_123 | 10 |
| 5/7/2021 | b | J_123 | 10 |
| 29/6/2021 | c | M_324 | 15 |
| 30/6/2021 | c | M_324 | 15 |
| 2/7/2021 | c | M_324 | 15 |
| 5/7/2021 | c | M_324 | 15 |

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server?

Comment: Can you also show us your current query attempt!

Answer (score 0):

if I didn't do any mistake :

```
select c.date , a.project, a.person, c.wordid, a.amount/ count(c.date) over(partition by c.wordid) Price
from tableA a
join tableB b
    on a.person = b.person
join tableC c
    on c.wordid = b.wordid
    and c.businessday = 'Y'
    and c.Date between a.StartDate and a.EndDate
```

Comment: probably needs count(distinct c.date) and add project to the partition by

Answer (score 0):

I think you may need aggregation for a more general case -- if multiple people, for instance, are working on the same project/workid:

```
select date, project, workid, sum(amount / num_days)
from (select t3.date , t1.project, t1.person, c.workid, 
             t1.amount,
             count(c.date) over (partition by t1.person, t1.project) as num_days
      from t1 join
           t2
           on t2.person = t1.person join
           t3
           on t3.workid = t2.workid and
              t3.date between t1.startdate and t1.enddate and
              t3.businessday = 'Y'
    ) t
group by date, project, workid;
```